# Script to create document at the time of form submission suddenly not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have this existing script that creates a document based off of the results of the form submission and has been running fine for awhile now but all of a sudden this morning decided to stop working. I am not sure why it is failing, please help?

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var removaladdition = e.values[1]
   console.log(e.values[1]);
  var CustomerName = e.values[2];
  var TrustName = e.values[3];
  var TrustDate = e.values[4];
  var CoTrusteeNames = e.values[5];
  var DocLink = e.values[6];
  

  if (removaladdition == "Adding"){
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("19Bvki2NR50K8Bk4Trv7S9k-bXmAKzXaa_b2vAhasNgQ");
   var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1jxw0SBS9BmD8EobuXIiyY9_s3TKy_jvh");

   var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(CustomerName + ' Appointment Of Co-Trustees', templateResponseFolder);
   var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

   var body = doc.getBody();

   body.replaceText('{{Customer Name}}', CustomerName);
   body.replaceText('{{Trust Name}}', TrustName);
   body.replaceText('{{Trust Date}}', TrustDate);
   body.replaceText('{{Co-Trustee Names}}', CoTrusteeNames);

   doc.saveAndClose();}

  if (removaladdition == "Removing"){
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1bzVKq3IePcOSfnNk_Al2dBCpRTPjYrTjtRMZr477uqs");
   var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1jxw0SBS9BmD8EobuXIiyY9_s3TKy_jvh");

   var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(CustomerName + ' Removal Of Co-Trustees', templateResponseFolder);
   var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

   var body = doc.getBody();

   body.replaceText('{{Customer Name}}', CustomerName);
   body.replaceText('{{Trust Name}}', TrustName);
   body.replaceText('{{Trust Date}}', TrustDate);
   body.replaceText('{{Co-Trustee Names}}', CoTrusteeNames);

   doc.saveAndClose();}

}
```

edit: here is the execution log where it fails [it is the execution log showing the trigger from Feb 26,2024 at 10:44:24AM has failed. There is a message stating "No logs are available for this execution"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LFc0.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fail message would contain an important detail... maybe share that?